# No chlorate esters? Why?

Tags: organic-chemistry, esters

Why are there no chlorate esters? Or are they just undocumented or too unstable? I've seen perchlorate esters, but google "chlorate esters" and only perchlorate esters come up.

Comment: perchlorates have no lone pairs of electrons on the chlorine, which leads to a kinetic barrier to any number of reactions.  Chlorates do have such a lone pair, which gives access to various decompositions reactions, even if the absolute oxidation potential is lower.

Comment: @Lighthart Together with the fact that alkyl perchlorates aren't just nasty alkylants but rather shock sensitive - I remember some publications from the fromer ASD of the USAAF on the reaction of alkyl iodides with silver perchlorate and subsequent tests - it's not very astonishing that nobody bothered or came close enough to characterize alkyl chlorates.

Answer (score 3):

Your initial statement is wrong. There are organic chlorates. When you want to search compounds, try chemical search engine like PubChem or ChemSpider instead of google. Even google lead you to something if you read carefully. It is no reason that chlorate ester can not exist and they do exist. Below is the link to the PubChem entry of Choric Acid, Methyl Ester, which is Methyl Chlorate.

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/18695386#section=Top